# How to get a correct row_number reset using row_number()?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, analytics

Here's my [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/abb58/1).

Requirement: Every time `Entry Form` changes, then reset numbering on `new_form_line_no`

The last column `New_form_line_no` correctly resets as expected on **Line_number=7**.
But, also want it to reset on **line #3** because Entry_form changes from **PR** to **OM**.

Where should I make my correction to get the following results?

```
20  1   1   R   OM  1
20  2   1   N   PR  1
20  3   2   R   OM  1 --This should reset to 1
20  4   3   A   OM  2
20  5   4   2   OM  3
20  6   5   P   OM  4
20  7   47  S   OL  1
20  8   48  A   OL  2
20  9   49  T   OL  3
20  10  50  2   OL  4
20  11  51  T   OL  5
20  12  52  L   OL  6
20  13  53  S   OL  7
20  14  54  O   OL  8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the first two records can appear in either order since they both have the same values in columns used in `ORDER BY` clause. If you don't mind that, or you have another way to determine which should be first (and you can alter the `ORDER BY` in analytic functions below), you can try following solution:

```
SELECT
    data.*,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY entry_id, entry_form, same_as_prev_or_next
                        ORDER BY entry_seq) AS new_form_line_no_2
  FROM (
    SELECT
      entry_id,
      row_number() OVER (ORDER BY entry_id, entry_seq) AS line_number,
      entry_seq,
      entry_text,       
      entry_form,       
      CASE
        WHEN lag(entry_form, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY entry_id ORDER BY entry_seq) = entry_form 
             OR lead(entry_form, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY entry_id ORDER BY entry_seq) = entry_form THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END AS same_as_prev_or_next
    FROM entrants
) data
ORDER BY entry_seq
;
```

It does not return what you expect, but it is due to the fact I mentioned - the order of the first two rows is inconclusive.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/abb58/18

Comment: I see what you mean. You've steered me in the right direction. Thanks.